# Using an HTML file as template for creating PDFs with ABCpdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, abcpdf

How do I use an HTML as a template then just replace the text in it and then convert it to PDF using ABCpdf? Are there any sample codes to do this? Thanks in advance!

I'm using C# ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf6net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/addimageurl.htm

Pass the absolute path of html template on the server into the AddImageUrl function.

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com/");
theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("htmlimport.pdf"));
theDoc.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

will be a nightmare, easiest way is to create a pdf of the web pages with blank spaces for your text, set the measurements to work as topdown and all you need is the X, Y fontname, size and then when your text is submitted you simply add to the specified coordinates.

Fast, very fast and you can just stream that back out as a new PDF